# Wrong accent/dagesh on birkat ha-Torah?

Tags: blessing

Why does -as far as I heard- hardly anyone pay attention to the accent on the word bachar or natan of the birkat ha-Tora [the accent/dagesh should be on the first syllable of both words according to all siddurim I have seen]but the words are pronounced with the accent on the second syllable.
The only time I became aware of this is when i got an aliyah in Amsterdam[Holland]and was corrected in by Rav Just זצ״ל who brought this to my attention.

Comment: Why do you think this is anything but ignorance and/or lazines? There are hundreds of common pronunciation mistakes throughout the liturgy.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Harold!

Comment: toda rabba.....you are probably right.....from rabbanim and chazanim [people who lajen]I would expect different and wonder if modern Hebrew/Ivrit may cause this specific ignoring of the accent in these 2 common words.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I've posted an answer, that I think is correct. Please verify that this is the reason with your rav. I'm curious if he concurs.

Answer (score 2):

This is an excellent question. Many people, including me, don't pay much attention as to why the accent has shifted.

This is a technique known as [*nasog achor*](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%92_%D7%90%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8_(%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F)). The basic idea is that two accented syllables should not appear consecutively. This technique is common in the Torah, for example, see Shemot 20:19:

> לֹא תַעֲשׂוּן, אִתִּי:  אֱ**לֹ**הֵי **כֶ**סֶף וֵאלֹ**הֵי** זָ**הָב**, לֹא תַעֲשׂוּ
> לָכֶם

I've bolded the places that have the accented syllable. The word אלהֵי usually has it's accent on the final syllable, and this is how it is in the 2nd occurrence. In the 1st occurrence, the word כֶסֶף has its accent on the 1st syllable. Therefore, the accent on אלהֵי moves back one syllable, so as not to place two accented syllables together.

Likewise, in the bracha, בנו is accented on the 1st syllable, and בחר is on the last, normally. Therefore, the accent on בחר moves backwards. Similar idea applies to לנו, which is accented on the 1st syllable. Therefore, the accent on נתן moves back one syllable.

I will see if I can research why this technique developed (though, I suspect that there is nothing more to it than the exact reason that I mentioned.) It seems that this technique applies to prayer as well as Torah reading, though, the rules of mispronouncing prayer words are not as "severe" as mispronouncing Torah words.

Keep in mind, that there are many exceptions to using this rule in Torah reading. Sometimes, a change of accent can change the meaning of the word from past to future tense, or there may be some other problem that occurs.

Comment: After having read your (undoubtedly more precise) answer, I particularly like the downvote on mine! :D

Comment: @Kazibácsi Pirkei Avot implies that one should not be a "self-imposed nebbish". I.e., one should not degrade himself. But, I see your point, and I'm glad that I was able to help you learn something. I know that this rule definitely applies to Torah reading. I'm not sure if it is required in prayer. However, I would assume, that proper pronunciation, even in prayer is important, even if not on the same requirement "level" as Torah reading.

Comment: I just wanted to say that even though my answer was not precise enough for being accepted, IMHO it shouldn't have been downvoted...

Comment: There are many reasons as to why questions and answers may be down-voted. Ideally, the person doing so, should comment, and, hopefully, suggest an improvement, if applicable. Often, as is the case. here, the voter either wants to remain anonymous, or just may not have had the time to comment.

Answer (score -1):

Even though I don't really get, how are the accents are marked in your siddurim (i.e. by a meteg), but the position of the cantillation sign is a good reference for stressing the correct syllable. In the case of בחר and נתן it is on the last syllable almost exclusively (check for locations in a concordance). However, I don't know, why your acquaintances are not following this rule.

Edit:
Please note that after both words come an auxiliary word - בנו, לנו - that may be connected to the previous word by a maqaf. In this case the stress can shift to the first syllable (see Bereshith 48:9, Chronicles 28:10 for reference).